# Unable to create schemas on Cloud SQL Postgres instance

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm running into a problem with Google's Cloud SQL solution, where I'm unable to create new schemas on my database. The rules are as follows:

```
testdb=> \du
                                            List of roles
     Role name     |                         Attributes                         |      Member of
-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------
 cloudsqladmin     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 cloudsqlagent     | Create role, Create DB                                     | {cloudsqlsuperuser}
 cloudsqlreplica   | Replication                                                | {}
 cloudsqlsuperuser | Create role, Create DB                                     | {}
 testuser          | Create role, Create DB                                     | {cloudsqlsuperuser}
 postgres          | Create role, Create DB                                     | {cloudsqlsuperuser}
```

Trying to create a new schema with the `testuser` results in a permission error.

```
testdb=> CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS testschema;
ERROR:  permission denied for database testdb
```

But I'm unable to `GRANT CREATE ON DATABASE testdb TO testuser;` because of the same permission issue.

Is there any way to give `testuser` the privilege to create schemas on its own?

Comment: i dont think so.

Comment: @Bira That seems silly. Do you know why? Is there any security issues or the likes?